# Qt How to use .qrc Resource file in a macro

Tags: c++, qt

I'm facing with this problem, using resource file in Qt5.10.
I selected all my graphic elements (previously "pointed" directly from the folder), from a resource file placed in my .pro Qt project file. When I placed an graphic item in my QtCreator, no problem: for example, editing a QLabel, selected pixmap->choose resource... and all is ok.
In same cases I arranged same macros in a .h header file to point a graphic item when in my program something happens or if user selects an option: the following is an example of my macros:

```
#define MY_ICON   (QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8("graphics/icon1.png")))
```

The project is compiled in "Shadow build" mode, so folder "graphics" containing all graphic items is placed in its original folder and not in its "build" folder.
Is there a way to "point" graphic items listed in my .qrc resource file using macro?

Comment: It does not matter whether you use a *macro* or not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point to a resource file by using the `:` prefix: `:/graphics/icon1.png`.

More in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).